# Font too small for code sections in headlines

Tags: bug, design, css, fonts

In a headline, sections marked as `code` use a font that is too small compared to the font of the headline.
Actually, the font size for code sections in title seems to be just the same as used for code sections in bold text:

## Headline 1 with `code` section

### Headline 2 with `code` section

#### Headline 3 with `code` section

**Bold line with `code` section**
Plain line with `code` section

I compared to askubuntu and found that the font adapts to the header font there.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the font size for `<code>` tags is specified as a fixed pixel value:

```
font-size: 13px;
```

The normal font size for plain text on this site is 15px, so replacing the CSS rule above with:

```
font-size: 86.67%;
```

would let the font size of `<code>` elements scale up in headers, while keeping the font size of code in plain text the same as it currently is.